# No tests executed! laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

What is this error? How to create simple test in laravel.

> PHPUnit 6.3.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Time: 130 ms, Memory: 4.00MB
>
> No tests executed!

tests/Feature/ReadArticle.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ReadArticle extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_user_can_view_home_page()
    {
        $this->get('/')->assertSee('وبسایت اکسبیر');
    }
}
```

Comment: how you run the test? what is the command you executed?

Comment: composer global require phpunit/phpunit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit - 'No tests executed' when using configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299206/phpunit-no-tests-executed-when-using-configuration-file)

Comment: run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` in your project folder. The version from your global phpunit might not same as your project require version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 possibilities :

Your test have to be

```
class ReadArticleTest extends TestCase
```

And so is your file name

You might use your global PHPunit instead of the laravel one.

Try this :

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 9):

If you used cmd line enter: `"./vendor/bin/phpunit"` to the root application. Don't forget about quotes!